# How to mock moment() in jest testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, momentjs

I need run some testing using jest and moment. Some of the imported functions work with moment current date (moment() ). But I can't seem to find a way of always run the same date for testing or mock moment constructor,  like pin moment date at moment('2020-07-05'), even if current day is 2020-07-10, so the test should always run under day 5.

My ./UtilsModule file:

```
import moment from 'moment'
export const getIntervalDates = groupOfDates => {
   const CURRENT_DATE = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   return getDates(CURRENT_DATE, groupOfDates ) //another function that does some extra processing;
};

export const nextDates = (date, group) => {
  let newDate= getIntervalDates(group);
}
```

My test.js file, and what i tried for:

```
import { nextDates ,getIntervalDates } from '../UtilsModule';
it('testing function', () => {
      const PAYLOAD = {...};
      const DATE= '2020-07-20';

      const SpyGetIntervalDates = jest.spyOn(UtilsModule, 'getIntervalDates');
      SpyGetIntervalDates.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ minAge: '2020-08-04' }));

      const nextDate = UtilsModule.nextDates(DATE, PAYLOAD);
      expect(nextDate).toEqual({ minDate: '2020-11-04' });
    });
```

I also tried, but i couldn't make it to work :

```
jest.mock('moment', () => {
  return () => jest.requireActual('moment')('2020-07-04');
});

and
global.moment = jest.fn(moment('2021-07-04'));
```

Comment: Where is `moment` defined? Whether jest.mock can affect it depends on this.

Comment: I have moment imported in my utilsModule

Comment: And UtilsModule is imported?.. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It's unclear what happens on your end and it's unclear how it can be fixed. Generally, jest.mock should work.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to test `nextDates` function with mocked `getIntervalDates` function. You need to do a little refactoring, you should keep the same reference for `getIntervalDates` function called inside `nextDates`. Then, you can use `jest.spyOn` to replace `getIntervalDates` with a mocked one.

E.g.

`utilsModule.js`:

```js
import moment from 'moment';

function getDates() {}

const getIntervalDates = (groupOfDates) => {
  const CURRENT_DATE = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  return getDates(CURRENT_DATE, groupOfDates);
};

const nextDates = (date, group) => {
  return exports.getIntervalDates(group);
};

exports.getIntervalDates = getIntervalDates;
exports.nextDates = nextDates;
```

`utilsModule.test.js`:

```js
const UtilsModule = require('./utilsModule');

describe('62736904', () => {
  it('testing function', async () => {
    const PAYLOAD = {};
    const DATE = '2020-07-20';

    const SpyGetIntervalDates = jest.spyOn(UtilsModule, 'getIntervalDates');
    SpyGetIntervalDates.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ minAge: '2020-08-04' }));

    const nextDate = await UtilsModule.nextDates(DATE, PAYLOAD);
    expect(nextDate).toEqual({ minAge: '2020-08-04' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62736904/utilsModule.test.js (11.51s)
  62736904
    ✓ testing function (3ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |      75 |      100 |   33.33 |      75 |                   
 utilsModule.js |      75 |      100 |   33.33 |      75 | 6-7               
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.892s
```